# Angular 4 Matdialog Template URL

Tags: angular, angular-material

I've succeeded in getting a MatDialog to open, but the contents are empty. I put what I wanted displayed in the ./game-window-dialog.html  file. Is this the correct place? This is my first StackOverflow question, so if I've done something wrong, please be kind. Thanks in advance!

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ngdw-game-window',
  templateUrl: './game-window.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./game-window.component.css']
})
export class GameWindowComponent implements OnInit {

  newgame: Game;

  constructor(private gameService: GameService, public dialog: MatDialog) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getGame();
  }

  getGame(): void {
    this.newgame = this.gameService.gameInit();
  }

  openDialog() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(GameWindowDialogComponent, {
      height: '350px'
    });
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'ngdw-game-window-dialog-component',
  templateUrl: './game-window-dialog.html'
})
export class GameWindowDialogComponent {
  constructor(
  public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<GameWindowDialogComponent>) { }
  onExitClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: if you could reproduce the same on https://plnkr.co/, it would be great. Others will be able to help you quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have put it in the correct place. Reasons the dialog would not render are:

- you did not declare the `GameWindowDialogComponent` in your `entryComponents` of your module: https://angular.io/api/core/NgModule#entryComponents
- you did not declare the `GameWindowDialogComponent` in your module: https://angular.io/api/core/NgModule#declarations

You need to do both of those things in order for this to work. Check both of those places.

Also, I'd recommend renaming it to `game-window-dialog.component.html`.

Comment: Thank you! Adding it to the entry components worked. As far as the name, the linter reccomended adding the app prefix.